# PHP and cURL extract variable from header

Tags: php, html, regex, curl

```
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Using this script, I get the output:
    http://website.com/632383970568166e82391f.png

And I need to extract the ID, which is abcdef and use it in another call. How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps, all you need is to change the regex to [`'/^Location:.*\/([^_]*)/mi'`](https://regex101.com/r/uV3sK9/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it works! One more question, though. What do I have to do to use the ID in another call? Example: Using that script, I get what I want, the ID. But I don't want to just find out the ID but to use the ID to access a new URL.

Comment: If you get it into a [`$matches[1]`](http://ideone.com/cH3QkB) you can use it anywhere later, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions or do this:

```
$url = "http://subdomain.website.com/something/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/20385425_632383970568166e82391f.png";
$urlParts = explode('/', $url)
$imgFileParts = explode('_', $urlParts[(count($urlParts) - 1)]);

$imgId = $imgFileParts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Simple regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/cJ9qS6/2)

```
$re = "/\\S+\\/([\\S]+)_/"; 
$str = "http://subdomain.website.com/something/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/20385425_632383970568166e82391f.png"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```